# MS word 2016 square brackets in reference list - ISO 690

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

im trying to change format of reference list in MS Word 2016 so it will be like this

```
[1]. pplk. žen. Ing. Sameš, Antonín. Beton a jeho význam pro opevňovací stavby. Praha : autor neznámý, 1637.
```

instead of this

```
1. pplk. žen. Ing. Sameš, Antonín. Beton a jeho význam pro opevňovací stavby. Praha : autor neznámý, 1637.
```

So the main issue is that im not able to insert square brackets around the reference number. I know i need to edit ISO690.xls file, but im not able to figure out where to find this one (i found standart reference in text, but this one...)

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers worked for me for Word 2016. Instead I used [this tutorial](http://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/change_the_type_of_brackets_in_citations.html) and it worked.

Find the style you want to edit in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style\`. Find these lines in the file:

```
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_OpenBracket" >
  <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
      <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
       <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:General/b:OpenBracket"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_CloseBracket" >
  <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
      <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
        <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:General/b:CloseBracket"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Change `xsl:value-of-select` tag to

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=INITIAL_CONTENTLCID]/b:General/b:OpenBracket"/>
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
```

for opening bracket and

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=INITIAL_CONTENTLCID]/b:General/b:CloseBracket"/>
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
```

for closing bracket

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Essential parts: "You should edit openbracket and closebracket styles as described and it will do it". This explains what tags should be changed inside the file. There is also a link to full tutorial. Could you be more specific on what should be edited?

Comment: "As described" doesn't really mean much without the description, which is behind the link.

Comment: I've looked at more than 15 solutions and this was the most straight forward, which also solved my problem. Thank you @KarolisRyselis

Answer (score 2):

#### I need to edit ISO690.xls file

Some information on which stylesheet to change is located at
[Word 2007 citations, should be simple, but... (solved)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/240589-Word-2007-citations-should-be-simple-but-solved), which also contains instructions.

For Word 2007 the file you need to change is `ISO690Nmerical.XSL`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Bibliography\Style\ISO690Nmerical.XSL
```

Someone has made the required changes available at [ISO 690 - Numeric Reference with Square Brackets](https://bibword.codeplex.com/releases/view/14646).

You could see if these changes will work for Word 2016.

> I found that "Yves" on CodePlex has already done the work and released [ISO690NmericalSquare.XSL](https://bibword.codeplex.com/releases/view/14646).
>
> After downloading this to %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\Bibliography\Style and restarting Word (2007 in my case – there’s anecdotal evidence to suggest it would work for Office14/2010 too),
>
> I have a new option in the bibliography style dropdown and my citations are all labelled with square parentheses.

Source [Changing Word’s bibliography style to use square parentheses](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2012/01/changing-words-bibliography-style-to-use-square-parentheses.htm)

Comment: thanks for your effort, i know everything of this, but still im stucked that i can change brackets in whole text, but generated reference list is still without brackets

Comment: @LubosSuk you could select all text (CTRL+A) and hit F9 to update all fields. If you edited the xml file (not created a copy) and restarted Word, you should be able to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the changes in the versions of ISO690Nmerical.xsl available from the web only affect Citations (surrounding the author list with square brackets).

If you want to modify the Bibliography so that you get references numbered "[1]" etc. instead of "1." etc., then what you need to do is
find and open the .xsl file (you can use Notepad), and if you have not already make a copy, save a copy. Here, with Word 2016 from Office 365 on Windows 10, it was in

```
C:\Users\installer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style
```

Then , it depends on whether you are using the original ISO690.xsl or ISO690Nmerical.xsl that came with Word, or the one which came from BibWord, which is structured very differently.

(If it is the ISO690Nmerical.xsl that came with Word, if you search for `1029` you should find some code that displays a title in Czech (I'm just jumping to a conclusion based on your sample text). You could usefully modify that display title. But what you really need to look for is

```
string-length(normalize-space($BibReference))
```

You should then see some XSL that looks something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space($BibReference)) > 0">
  <xsl:value-of select="b:RefOrder"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_Dot"/><xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_Space"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$BibReference"/>
</xsl:if>
```

You need to change that so it looks like this:

```
<!--change reference to look like [1] rather than 1.-->
<xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space($BibReference)) > 0">
  <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="b:RefOrder"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_Space"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$BibReference"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Save the .xsl, change your bibliographic style to something else and back again, then see if your results are updated.

If it's one of the other .xsl s, it may be different. I don't have time to check right now, but have a look and see what you can find out.